# Soyatec modifies my existing java files, can I stop that?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

If I use Soyatec studio edition upon my existing project, it will go through the java files and add lots of comments. Can I stop this and ask Soyatec doesn't modify any of my java files?

Comment: +1 good question. I have this problem too.